# Android getAssets().openFd(string) - file not found

Tags: android, audio, file-io, filenotfoundexception

getAssets()openFD() fails.

```
AssetFileDescriptor fileFD=null;
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Music/ckyws8.wav");
fileFD = getAssets().openFd(file.toString()); //FAILS
```

The log shows:
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/Music/ckyws8.wav

Even though `file.exists()` returns `true`
 and also the test:

```
File tempath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Music");          
int files = tempath.list().length;
for(int f=0;f<files;f++){
    Log.d(LOG_TAG,tempath.list()[f].toString());    
}
```

returns a list containing `ckyws8.wav`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

`AssetManager` is for accessing your application's assets, which is the contents of the `assets/` directory in your project's source tree. It is not for accessing files on internal or external storage, which is why your code does not work.

Comment: Previous answer, short as it may be, was helpful. In case others run into the same misconception, heres what I have changed to make the code work.

Answer (score 1):

Previous answer, short as it may be, was helpful. In case others run into the same misconception, heres what I have changed to make the code work:

First of since it not a file in the assets `AssetFileDescriptor fileFD=null;` is changed to `FileDescriptor fileFD=null;` keeping in mind that they have different function and other parts of the code needs to be changed aswell.

To get a `FileDescriptor` a `FileInputStream` is needed, so the other part of the code reads:

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Music/ckyws8.wav");//same as before
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
fileFD = fis.getFD();
```

Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

correct way of reading asset file stream is as below:
`InputStream is = ctx.getAssets().open("fileName");`